# how to handle the passsword encrytion in Https request in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI3Jt.png)When i started recording the application in jmeter, then i found that password is getting encrypted,the value which i am passing in application like username  password to login the application, After recording the application in jmeter then in Http request iam getting password is getting encrypted and receiving the response in jmeter request, let me know how to handle encrypted password in jmeter.

example :

Client side is passing details to login the application.

username : sirajdws , password : 123456

Server side we are getting

"password":"U2FsdGVkX1+4B2RcuHgnZ6djgFQTV64qGtMxbLDMQ6s"

which is observed in jmeter http request. in given below image.

Comment: I cannot understand your description and I do not see what question you are asking. The one in the title is much to unfocused. I recommend splitting your post into parts which can be understood. Complete but short sentences, with punctuation separating them, could be a good tool to achieve that.

Comment: i attached the screenshot and modified the sentence , i hope u can understand..

Answer (score 0):

If it's client-side encryption you should be able to use [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) in order to determine the [encryption algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cryptographic_algorithms) and the [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) if any, this way you should be able to encode the password using JMeter's [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) or implement the client-side encryption logic using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Alternatively if you don't have to simulate many users you can capture the encrypted passwords for each login and put the credentials into a CSV file so you can read it back using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)